# Why these subsequent "dup2" calls exist in android boot code

Tags: android, c, linux

In the linux init.c file in the android source i found this code:

```
static void open_console()
{
    int fd;
    if ((fd = open(console_name, O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    }
    ioctl(fd, TIOCSCTTY, 0);
    dup2(fd, 0);
    dup2(fd, 1);
    dup2(fd, 2);
    close(fd);
}
```

Source:
[Link to android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-cts-4.4_r1/init/init.c)

After opening the console device succefully, it ioctl to some fork operation and then continues to duplicate the file descriptors on the first three, then closes them all (since closing one will close them all) and exit.

What is the purpose of this? Why would i want to make sure the file descriptors that are being assigned to 0,1,2 are close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know the file descriptors for 0, 1 and 2 are `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) simply gets an opened file descriptor and creates a duplicate entry of it into the file descriptors table (and also closes the new file descriptor if it was already opened).

Closing `fd` does not also cause closing the file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 once they were dup-ed. So your initial assumption seems wrong - you would not end up with these descriptors closed, but instead they would get redirected to that console descriptor. After that, fd gets closed since it is no longer needed - `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` are all mapped to either the console or `/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks! i assumed it was closed since their offset were linked, but i guess i did not check it.